# My Aggregation Query skip,order is not working propery with java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

Here is my Java code. skip missing some records. also order is not working.

```
AggregateIterable<Document> propertiesDoc = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
                    Aggregates.match(queryNew),
                     Aggregates.group("$similarGroup", Accumulators.sum("count", 1),Accumulators.first("data", "$$ROOT")),
                     Aggregates.skip(skipCount),
                    Aggregates.limit(searchRequest.getItemsPerPage()),
                    Aggregates.sort(descending("salePrice")))
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. there was multiple issues.

1. there was some records missing the field "similarGroup".
2. Sort was not working properly, and below code worked.

> AggregateIterable propertiesDoc =
> collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.match(queryNew),
> Aggregates.group("$similarGroup", Accumulators.sum("count", 1),
> Accumulators.first("data", "$$ROOT")),
> Aggregates.sort(Sorts.descending("data.salePrice")),
> Aggregates.skip(skipCount),
> Aggregates.limit(searchRequest.getItemsPerPage())));